# jquery each function on string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wrote a function in javascript which takes title attributes of `<tr>` calls ajax then after some operation it retreive some title attributes from them. depending on that title attribute i want to remove those `<tr>` rows

```
function currentTicketStatus() {
    var ids = '';
    $('tbody tr[title]').each(function() {
        ids += ((ids == '') ? '' : ',') + $(this).attr('title');
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxExecute.aspx?Fn=CTS',
        type: 'POST',
        context: document.body,
        cache: false,
        data: 'Tickets=' + ids,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response != '') {
                if (response.substr(0, 5) != 'ERROR') {
                    var sTickets = response.split('|');

                    sTickets.each(function() {
                        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Example : at the time of ajax call `ids="100,101,102,103,104"` after ajax call `sTickets="101|102"` . Now remove those rows with attributes of sTickets

HTML (Not Exactly )

```
<tbody>
<tr title="100"> some data part </tr>
<tr title="101"> some data part </tr>
<tr title="102"> some data part </tr>
<tr title="103"> some data part </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I guess problem is in each function.

Comment: the `this` in the last each is a string (a title) not a `<tr>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `this` in the `each` is a "title" (a string), you need the DOM element (the `<tr>`) instead

```
sTickets.each(function() {
  $('tbody tr[title="'+ this +'"]').remove();
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tAb8F/1/)

Comment: Page remains steady ..i.e.without load and all that <tr> should get removed. i am able to get alert on sTickets but row not removed..!!

Comment: It does not get into each function() i put alert inside it displaying some msg but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your success function :

```
 success: function(response) {
            if (response != '') {
                if (response.substr(0, 5) != 'ERROR') {
                    var sTickets = response.split('|');
                    $.each(function(i,v){ $('tr[title=' + v + ']')  }).remove();
                }
            }
```

Explanation:

**1- SELECT DOM element by attribute :**

```
   $('[ATTRIBUTE=VALUE]') // $('[title="myTitle"]')
```

you can find more in this link http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

**2 - $.each Iteration**

which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays.

more : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Page remains steady ..i.e.without load and all that <tr> should get removed. i am able to get alert on sTickets but row not removed..!!